# Pass NSString from didUpdateLocations in NSObject to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I created an iOS project and I implemented `didUpdateLocations` to get my location in a `NSObject`. I want to get the longitude and the latitude from the delegate to a `UIViewController` but the result is always null even to test the `addObserver` I couldn't. In the bottom there is a sample that I did and it shows my location in the label. I implemented `didUpdateLocations` in the viewcontroller and without a `NSObject` Class.

This my code in the `NSObject`:

```
#import "GpsModel.h"

@implementation GpsModel{
    CLLocation *crnLoc;
}

@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize longitude;
@synthesize latitude;

- (void) initLocation {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //[self showAlert];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
    longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
    latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
}

@end
```

and this is my ViewController :

```
#import "GpsViewController.h"

@interface GpsViewController ()

@end

@implementation GpsViewController{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@synthesize gpsView;
@synthesize gpsModel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    gpsView = [[GpsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthtScreen, heightScreen)];
    [self.view addSubview:gpsView];
    gpsModel = [GpsModel new];
    [gpsModel initLocation];
    gpsView.longitudeLabel.text = gpsModel.longitude;
    [gpsView.longitudeLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    gpsView.latitudeLabel.text = gpsModel.latitude;
    [gpsView.latitudeLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if(object == gpsView.longitudeLabel)
    {
        NSLog(@"long");
    }
    if(object == gpsView.latitudeLabel)
    {
        NSLog(@"lat");
    }
}
@end
```

And this my code without the creation of a NSObject Class :

```
@interface GpsViewController ()

@end

@implementation GpsViewController{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *crnLoc;
}

@synthesize gpsView;
@synthesize gpsModel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    gpsView = [[GpsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthtScreen, heightScreen)];
    [self.view addSubview:gpsView];
    [self initLocation];

}
- (void) initLocation {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [self showAlert];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"position long : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude]);
    NSLog(@"position lat : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude]);
    gpsView.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
    [gpsView.longitudeLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    gpsView.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
    [gpsView.latitudeLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if(object == gpsView.longitudeLabel)
    {
        NSLog(@"observe1");

    }
    if(object == gpsView.latitudeLabel)
    {
        NSLog(@"observe2");

    }
}
```

and this is my view that contains 2 labels

```
@implementation GpsView{
    CGFloat _originY;
}

@synthesize longitudeLabel;
@synthesize latitudeLabel;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _originY = 50;
        [self _initView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self _initView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)_initComponents {
    longitudeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    latitudeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}

- (void)_initView {
    [self _initComponents];
    [self _createComponentView];
}

-(void) _createComponentView {
    _originY = [self createLabel:_originY :longitudeLabel :self];
    [self addSubview:longitudeLabel];
    _originY = [self createLabel:_originY :latitudeLabel :self];
    [self addSubview:latitudeLabel];
}
```

Comment: Did you use similar or real device? Did `crnLoc` is equal `nil`?

Comment: Yes I did use it in a real device . Actually crnLoc is not nil . I displayed in my console my longitude and my latitude but only inside didUpdateLocations it works

Answer (score 0):

You are observing text in a label, that is set only once in your didLoad method and it will never be updated after the location update. If you want to use observers you should observe your gpsModel instance and latitude/longitude properties in it. And in the observeValueForKeyPath delegate method you should update your text labels.

Comment: Before observing the text in the label , I couldn't display the longitude in the label . I'm getting it null from my model

Comment: where can I update the Label in the view controller ?

Comment: You will be able to display correct values only when CoreLocation will receive first location update. Before it the location will be null which is correct.

Comment: As I said if you want to use observers you should observe values in your gpsModel and in observeValueForKeyPath you will be able to update your labels

Comment: ok for the observers I get it but for the label that's the hard part . I tried to put everything in the same viewcontroller and it display the text in the label . It works fine .But when I changed to to nsobject I couldn't get the string from it

Comment: Yes, the code that was working and more explanations about what you want to achieve

Comment: I updated my question by adding the sample that it did work. I got the my location in the label and in the console it displayed the nslog in the observeValueForKeyPath

Comment: It a UIView where i create my view which it contain 2 label. I updated my post so you can check it

Comment: Ah excuse me it's an NSObject class